# Fork safely from PHP

Tags: php, bash, fork

From the get go, let me say that I'm trying to avoid using `pcntl_fork()`

For this example, lets imagine that I'm trying to fork many instances of the 'dig' command line application. In reality the same script will be used for different command line apps.

Right now I'm using php **exec** and appending **&** to the command so that bash runs it in the background.

E.g

```
exec("dig google.com &");
exec("dig yahoo.com &");
```

and so on...

This successfully creates multiple processes of **dig** running parallel.

The problem I'm having is that the number of processes is rising steadily until the system crashes. Essentially it's a fork bomb.

I tried to combat this by checking the number of running processes using `ps ax | wc -l`
and only launching more if it's below X.

E.g (running on a loop)

```
if 80 processes are running, i'll launch another 20. 
if 70 processes are running, i'll launch another 30.
```

The problem is, that even with this check in place, the number of processes continues to rise until the system crashes or it hits the operating systems **max user processes**

Can anyone give me some hints on how I can fork effectively (mass) without raping all the system resources? I can't see why this current method isn't working tbh.

Comment: What are the codes snippet for handling the while-loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a management process, I suggest you watch over the created subprocesses. Save the PID of every subscript you start:

```
$running[] = exec("process www.google.com &  echo $!");
```

Where `$!` will return the PID of the backgrounded process, adding it to a list in PHP. Then in your management loop, just recheck if the processes are still active:

```
do {
    foreach ($running as $i=>$pid) {
        if (!posix_getpgid($pid)) {
             unset($running[$i]);
             // restart
        }
}   }
```

I don't think it's very elegant or reliable. pcntl_fork is often the better approach, but you din't elaborate on your actual scripts. But maybe this works in your case.

Comment: This is essentially the code right now:


$process_count = trim(`ps ax | wc -l`);

while(1){
 
 if($process_count < 150){
  
  //fork another process
  
 } else {
  
  //Do nothing, wait for process_count to lower
  
 }
 
}

Comment: Mario, I'll try your code now. I was hoping to not have to go that route but you're right that it might be my only solution outside of using pcntl_fork. I'll post back soon :)

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to use `uptime` to check system load.

Comment: Thanks but that won't make much difference in this scenario. Ideally the aim for this is to stay within X number of processes running at any one time. In my tests, the system load has always remained low, the only problem i've encountered is maxing out the number of processes allowed to run at once.

I could increase the number of processes that can run at any one time but that doesn't solve the problem that the script is continuing to go over the number of processes I want to run at any single time.

Comment: Then you may want to use `ulimit` to limit the user running it from killing whole system, and then use 'ps ax | wc -l` or `ps ax | grep dig | grep -v grep | wc -l` to limit the number of processes, as described above. It should work if you check it right, if it doesn't please describe what process count command returns for you, maybe it's some incompatibility in options...

Comment: Hi StasM. I can prevent the system crashing using ulimit, yes. However that's more of a plaster than a solution. Cos the script will go tits up if it manages to hit that limit. 

The command I described above successfully runs the number of processes running on the system. That's why I can't understand how the script still manages to launch too many processes.

Comment: I guess the code snippet from the script would help, maybe the error is there.